# Sitecore Content Editor - Adds Styling

Tags: c#, html, css, sitecore

Whenever a picture is edited (Even if no height or width has been touched) then it adds:

```
style="height: 123px; width: 123px;"
```

Before edit:

```
<p><img alt="" height="123" width="123" src="~/media/123" /></p>
```

After edit:

```
<p><img alt=""  
src="~/media/123;h=123&amp;w=123" style="height: 123px; width: 123px;" /></p>
```

The problem is that the style height and width added by Sitecore messes with the responsiveness of the picture, is there any way to remove this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to remove those attributes in a consistent fashion would be to strip the attributes on render of the image by overriding this default pipeline: Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue.

Here is how it can be done:

First add the following class to your solution:

```
namespace Custom.Business.SC.Extensions.Pipelines.RenderField
{
    using System;

    using HtmlAgilityPack;

    using Sitecore;
    using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
    using Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField;

    /// <summary>Class that renders a rich text field with removed image dimensions.</summary>
    public class GetFieldValue : Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue
    {
        /// <summary>The process method.</summary>
        /// <param name="args">The render field arguments.</param>
        public new void Process(RenderFieldArgs args)
        {
            base.Process(args);

            // Do not modify output if the field is not a rich text field,
            // or if the page is in page editor mode
            if (args.FieldTypeKey != "rich text" || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args.FieldValue) || Context.PageMode.IsPageEditorEditing)
            {
                return;
            }                       

            // stripping dimension attributes from images
            Profiler.StartOperation("Stripping dimension attributes from image field: " + args.FieldName);
            args.Result.FirstPart = this.StripImageDimensions(args.Result.FirstPart);
            Profiler.EndOperation();
        }

        /// <summary>The strip image dimensions.</summary>
        /// <param name="text">The text.</param>
        /// <returns>The <see cref="string"/>.</returns>
        private string StripImageDimensions(string text)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
            {
                return text;
            }

            var outText = text;
            try
            {
                var doc = new HtmlDocument();
                doc.LoadHtml(outText);
                this.StripAttribute(doc, "width");
                this.StripAttribute(doc, "height");
                this.StripAttribute(doc, "style");
                outText = doc.DocumentNode.WriteContentTo();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }

            return outText;
        }

        /// <summary>The strip attribute.</summary>
        /// <param name="doc">The doc.</param>
        /// <param name="attribute">The attribute.</param>
        private void StripAttribute(HtmlDocument doc, string attribute)
        {
            // HtmlAgilityPack returns null instead of an empty collection when the query finds no results.  
            var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(string.Format("//img[@{0}]", attribute));
            if (nodes == null || nodes.Count.Equals(0))
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {
                node.Attributes[attribute].Remove();
            }
        } 
    }  
}
```

Now make the appropriate config entry to replace the default pipeline with the custom one above. An include file is best practice but I’ve added both examples to try to be clear.

Example to patch in from app_config/include/custom.config file.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
            <sitecore>
              <pipelines>
                <renderField>
                  <processor type="Custom.Business.SC.Extensions.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue,     Custom.Business"
                    patch:instead="*[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
                </renderField>
              </pipelines>
            </sitecore>
    </configuration>
```

Or replace the entry in the web.config:

```
<renderField>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.SetParameters, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetTextFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.ExpandLinks, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <!--<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetImageFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />-->
  <processor type="Custom.Business.SC.Extensions.Pipelines.RenderField.GetFieldValue, Custom.Business" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetInternalLinkFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetMemoFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetDateFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.GetDocxFieldValue, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.AddBeforeAndAfterValues, Sitecore.Kernel" />
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.RenderField.RenderWebEditing, Sitecore.Kernel" />
</renderField>
```

Now you should be able to insert images into rich text fields as normal. The image will still display height and width when viewing the html view in the content editor. However once you view the content on the site you will see the attributes have been striped out.

Answer (score 0):

You can strip tags in the Sitecore Rich Text Editor

Reference: [Sitecore Rich Text Editor Series](https://codebuildplay.wordpress.com/category/rich-text-editor-series/)

> Under the hood of the RTE lies the Telerik RadEditor. This control has
> a property called “StripFormattingOnPaste” which is described on
> teleriks website here:
> [StripFormattingOnPaste Property](http://www.telerik.com/help/sitefinity/developer-manual/radeditor.net2-telerik.webcontrols.radeditor-stripformattingonpaste.html)
>
> The editor provides many different
> ways to strip tags

or Better use separate image field/type instead of adding image in Rich Text Editor.

> **What we removed**
>
> **Advanced Functionality** – we didn’t include items such as “insert form fields” since this is for superusers only. They can use other
> means to create forms (such as Web Forms for Marketers). We are also
> making an assumption that advanced users will likely be editing the
> HTML directly.
>
> **Obscure functionality** – for instance insert date/time isn’t something most of our clients will use, so unless there is a daily
> need for this, it’s not worth including.
>
> **“Don’t touch that”** – we have specific CSS styles set up for headings, so we don’t want users to have the ability to play with the
> text, so we’ve removed those functions

Reference: [Customizing Sitecore's rich text editor for better usability](http://www.nonlinearcreations.com/Digital/how-we-think/articles/2013/04/Customizing-Sitecores-rich-text-editor-for-better-usability.aspx?sc_lang=en)

Comment: They need to be able to add it in the Rich Text Editor though, since they need a lot of different texts and images from time to time, is there no way to remove the height + width style that is added ?